# Can I debug code in the parent iOS App when it is awoken by a WatchKit App/Extension?

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

I want to debug code in the `application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:` method of my AppDelegate.

If I debug the WatchKit App then when it launches the iOS App to call this method, the debugger is not attached. Is there a way to get the debugger to attach to the iOS App when it is launched from WatchKit as opposed to the Xcode run/debug command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup.

Run your WatchKit application via Xcode, then manually launch your associated iOS application on the simulator.

Once it's launched, use the Debug menu in Xcode to `Attach to Process…`. You'll see your iOS application running there.

[image: Attach to Process]

You'll then have two active debug sessions accessible in the Debug Navigator (`⌘+6`). You can switch between them there.

[image: Debug Navigator]

Comment: Thanks - the trick is launching the WatchKit App first... If I launched and attached the iOS app first, then pressing "play" in Xcode to run the WatchKit App would kill the attached iOS App. So I had to set a breakpoint in the WatchKit App right at the start (as it calls into the iOS App on startup), run that first and let it pause on the breakpoint, then launch iOS, attach process, then let the WatchKit App continue. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful for debugging WatchKit, but you can also set a process to wait until it's launched. In the Xcode menu, Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme…, then in the Info panel "Wait for executable to be launched."

Answer (score 1):

After you run your WatchKit app and it is attached to the debugger, manually open your iPhone app in the simulator by tapping on its icon.  Then in Xcode go to Debug -> Attach To Process in the menu and select your iPhone app.  Now Xcode should be attached to both your WatchKit extension and your iPhone app and you can set break points in either the iPhone app or your extension.